# How do I create a LSTM model with two inputs

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I have two csv files, the first one with two columns contains students' marks in different subjects and the second one with three columns is containg two student's ids and a comparison about the best one, so I have to train this data to get coefficients and make a score for each student.

I'm trying an LSTM model but I don't know how to use two files as inputs and how to choose train data and test one.

Comment: I think you might first concentrate on some basic requirements here. First, you need to be able to read a csv, `pandas` is a standard tool, there are a lot of tutorials for that matter. Then, you might want to do some research on "how to implement an LSTM" using tensorflow (or another DL tool). If you're lacking theory knowledge, you might consider "Sequence Model" course by coursera. StackOverflow is meant for answering technical question related to code and software, it doesn't provide tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a problem with the data I'm afraid.

You can not extract the note from that student because you do not have it. The only thing that occurs to me is that you could reorient your problem and do the following:

1. Create an LSTM that evaluates the subjects of a student.
2. Create a network that compares you with another student and tells
   you if it is better or worse (through step 1). It is known as the
   Siamese network.

You have what is said LSTM siamese.

What you could do in prediction is to know if a student based on the grades in their subjects have better or worse than another student.

**EDIT**:

Maybe is useful one architecture similar than these.

[image]

Use LSTM to get the information of any subject and corresponent mark.

When the information is condensed, I concatenate this information and the student one-hot.

We use a Dense or multiple dense to get mark with sigmoid activation in the last layer.

We use a loss function to maximize the note of a with respect b when a is better than b. And otherwise.

y_i is your target in 1 o -1. Is 1 when the student a is better than the student b, and is -1 when the student a is worse than student b.

I have never tried this type of loss function, so I can not tell you if it works or not. It is based on the loss that SVM uses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine

Maybe another user can guide you better.

Comment: Actually, the first csv file contains a column of students ids and a second column with notes (marks)!!

Comment: Yes but in each subject, do you want to estimate a student's grade for a particular subject? What data are you going to have in the prediction stage?

Comment: I want to predict coefficients from those two files and caculate a score for each student based on these coefficients

Comment: this is the problem text : A training receives each year a certain number of applications. These files contain both qualitative elements (which will not be considered here) and quantitative elements concerning the marks obtained in a certain number of subjects by the candidates.
It is assumed that to help classify these files, those responsible for this training would like to calculate, for each student, a sort of overall score that would be a weighted average of his or her different grades. Unfortunately, these officials find it difficult to agree on the coefficients to set.

Comment: On the other hand, they are generally in agreement when it is necessary, for a pair of files, to decide which of the two is the best. We propose here to learn the coefficients rather than fix them. To do this, we provide you with a data set that indicates, for each pair of students, the student that the training managers have ranked the highest of the two in the admission list.The constraints are as follows: the final score assigned to each student must be a linear combination of his grades;each coefficient must be positive;the sum of the coefficients must be equal to 1.